# Tile View for jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to create some kind of control or if it exists a tile view control in jquery that is similar to this control http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TileView/FirstLook , the link of example is a silverlight control... but I need this control in jquery

Comment: Since it's telerik, and their jQuery library is KendoUI.  Their site says they plan to implement nearly the same functionality in March 2012. If you can wait that long for an easy plugin.

Comment: But in present is there any control similar?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). See [this example page](http://tyler-designs.com/masonry-ui/) for using Masonry with sortable/resizable boxes.

For heavier-weight window controls, you might look at [SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/) or [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs). These are much bigger frameworks than just providing a control or a widget, however, and have a fair learning curve to match.

Comment: But I need some features like selecting, drag, drop and maximize - minimize